# java - reading .properties file and storing it in properties object

Tags: java, swing, properties-file

As mentioned in the title I have to read a `.properties` file in java and store it in a `Properties` object. I use a `jFileChooser` from java swing to get the file, which actually works, then I pass the file to a new window as calling arguments and then I use the `load()` method to store it in a `Properties` object but I get the `java.lang.NullPointerException` error. I hope I was clear as trying to explain it.

*This is the code:*

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e3) { //when button is pressed
            JFileChooser fc2 = new JFileChooser (new File("C:\\Users\\Ciurga\\workspace\\PropertiesManager"));
            fc2.setDialogTitle("Load Default Values File");
            fc2.setFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".properties", "Properties File"));
            int result = fc2.showOpenDialog(null);
            if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                df = fc2.getSelectedFile(); //getting selected file and storing it in "df" which will be passed as calling argument     
                defaultNameTextField.setText(df.getName());
            }
        }
```

*This is how I pass the file to the other window:*

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1) {
            FormWindow w1 = new FormWindow (df, lf); //when button is pressed, create new window passing the files i got with jFileChooser
        }
```

*And this is how I tried to store it in a `Properties` object:*

```
private static Properties propDef;
private static Properties propLim; 

private void run(File def, File lim) {
    try {
        propDef.load(new FileInputStream(def));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        propLim.load(new FileInputStream(lim));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(propDef.getProperty("name"));

}
```

Thank you guys, as you said I only had to initialize it and now it seems to work correctly, it was a simple error but I'm actually a beginner in java.
This is what I changed:

```
private static Properties propDef = new Properties();
private static Properties propLim = new Properties();
```

Comment: Did you initialize `propDef` and  `propLim` ? If it is not the case, they are `null` , and calling `load` on them will give you `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

You never initialised propDef, thats why you get the NullPointerException.

If you did initialise it, please provide the code!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your `propDef` and `propLim` are null and when you call  `propDef.load(new FileInputStream(def));` you get a NPE because `load` method is instance method.